# kwallet get password as root user

Tags: permissions, password, kwallet

I'm currently setting up a borgmatic backup job that should get the repository from the kwallet using the following command:

```
kwallet-query -r systeembackup kdewallet -f borg
```

But unfortunately it triggers this error when I run borgmatic:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Couldn't start kwalletd:  QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected", "Not connected to D-Bus server")
passcommand supplied in BORG_PASSCOMMAND failed: Command '['kwallet-query', '-r', 'systeembackup', 'kdewallet', '-f', 'borg']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Because the backup job is run as the root user to be able to perform a full system backup, the command is not able to open the KDE wallet.

I tried running it as my own user:

```
sudo -i -u ik kwallet-query -r systeembackup kdewallet -f borg
```

Without success:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-ik'
Couldn't start kwalletd:  QDBusError("org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected", "Not connected to D-Bus server")
Wallet kdewallet not found
```

Also not by setting the XDG variable first:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000; sudo -i -u ik kwallet-query -r systeembackup kdewallet -f borg
```

Is there a way to the password from the wallet as a privileged process/user?

Comment: I think the export is not working for the sudo part. Try `sudo -i -u ik export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000;kwallet-query -r systeembackup kdewallet -f borg`

Comment: @MichaelD That solves it!

Comment: I used runuser to solve the problem for my use case
`sudo runuser -u your_user -- kwallet-query ...`

Comment: `export` is not required for per-command environment variables if you omit the semicolon so it's "part of" the command, e.g. `sudo -i -u ik XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 kwallet-query -f borg -r systeembackup kdewallet`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by setting

```
encryption_passcommand: sudo -E -u InsertUserNameHere kwallet-query -r borg-passphrase kdewallet
```

in `/etc/borgmatic/config.yaml`.

My borg passphrase was set with:

```
head -c 32 /dev/urandom | base64 -w 0 | kwalletcli -Pe borg-passphrase -f Passwords
```